# Rebuild an already built React project

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, build, swagger

I have cloned a git repo regarding the swagger framework for API documentations. It is an already built project, ready to run.

However, I would like to effect some styling changes, hide certain elements and tweak with the default links and examples it provides. Indeed the changes have been easy, but by saving them and re-running the project as a web app they were not visible. It is my understanding that one has to rebuild a project in order for changes to come live. It is a React app, running on node.js, so I proceeded by following the script commands within package.json and rebuilt the project.

Still, although the changes have been saved within the dev files, they are not visible within the web app. Inspecting the DOM elements of interest confirms that no changes are in effect. My question is ***whether I can rebuild this project so that the changes will eventually become available, or if there is another way to achieve this***.

Comment: One thing you can  try is to clear the browser cache.

Comment: @tromgy I have already cleared it. Maybe, I'll try to isolate all dev files and build them anew, but I was hoping to avoid that.